# FileNotFoundError when import scipy on anaconda python

Tags: python, scipy, file-not-found

Operating system: Windows 10 Home
Python interpreter: Anaconda with python 3.8.8

I have installed the scipy module on anaconda using "conda install
scipy==1.6.2" and it states "# All requested packages already installed.". However, when I opened python ide and import scipy, the below error appears.

The way I try to solve is through reinstalling scipy module and "conda update --all". However, these all fails. Any ways to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

```
import scipy

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\tys\.conda\envs\renv\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 130, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\tys\.conda\envs\renv\lib\site-packages\scipy\_distributor_init.py", line 59, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "C:\Users\tys\.conda\envs\renv\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\tys\.conda\envs\renv\lib\site-packages\scipy\.libs\libbanded5x.3OIBJ6VWWPY6GDLEMSTXSIPCHHWASXGT.gfortran-win_amd64.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

Comment: 1. Which python is being opened? Is it the main installation within your computer, or is it the environment's python?

2. Is the environment activated?

Comment: anaconda python environment is opened through using CMD and "conda activate (my-environment)" to open python in anaconda environment. During installation of anaconda, I have clicked both "register to PATH" and "use anaconda python as system interpreter".

Answer (score 0):

You should try the solution given here (https://github.com/pytroll/satpy/issues/1835):

```
conda install -c defaults scipy
```

It worked for me.